# Modifying Openwrt built in package files

Tags: linux, makefile, package, cross-compiling, openwrt

Am able to build /compile the package for openwrt in my ubuntu machine , but when I try to re-install the compiled .ipk the files not getting modified in openwrt.
What changes need to made in Makefile to make this effect??

Comment: like to know possibility  to replace the already built in installed *base-files for openwrt
eg files like : /etc/profile

Comment: Could you show how you rebuild and reinstall it? Do you remove it manually, before install the new one?

Comment: No I used  Makefile to remove a file .Used commands  inside  
define Package/<package name>/install
$(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/etc/
rm  $(1)/etc/profile

But after i build an ipk  for openwrt the profile file inside /etc not removed ?? Can i know whether its possible??

Comment: you can manually delete the package from console, run `opkg remove [name]`

Comment: Sir, i want Makefile to do this activity , not manual remove

Comment: Guys as I am stuck still now, I am thinking of following another path ,  as how to generate sysupgrade.bin file for a particular package? Is it possible??

Comment: Is it possible to include --force-overwrite option inside the onclick of "install" for any particular package in the web page??